# None of my variables are declared (C++)

Tags: c++

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
cout << "Ist yoo acited? \n"
char j
cin >> input;
cout << input;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;}
```

It says in the error message that 'j' is undeclared.
I'm obviously new, and just trying out stuff out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is too basic.  Compiler gives the error and OP can look it up easily in a book.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a semicolon at the end of `j`'s declaration, and your `cout` command. You may also wish to provide `j` with a default value. Also, you don't seem to have declared the variable `input`.

Comment: Actually `j` should be `input`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a couple semi-colons( `;` ) and you also didn't declare `input`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    cout << "Ist yoo acited? \n";
    char j, input;
    cin >> input;
    cout << input;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```